# Can i call an activity's view from a class?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a pretty cool problem that I keep trying to figure out.
I have an Activity named Bill, it has a Textview and a RecyclerView. I plan to use textview to count the bills I have while recyclerView will show those bills.
But the problem is that in the adapter when I am processing the Viewholder data for the RecyclerView, it has a button to clear the Bill in case the customer returns or cancels the order.
And the problem is now I don't know how to setText for TextView, can anyone please answer this question for me? Thanks.

Here is the Bill activity i mention

```
    package anhtuan.example.sample.feature;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import anhtuan.example.sample.Bill.Bill_RecyclerView_Adapter;
    import anhtuan.example.sample.DAO.DAO;
    import anhtuan.example.sample.Model.BillModel;
    import anhtuan.example.sample.R;

    public class Bill extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView bill_total;
    RecyclerView bill_RecyclerView;

    ArrayList<BillModel>bills;
    DAO dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bill);
        setTitle("Bill");
        bill_total = findViewById(R.id.bill_total);
        bill_RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.bill_recyclerView);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        bills=new ArrayList<>();
        dao = new DAO(Bill.this);
        bills= dao.getDSBill();

        bill_total.setText("Bills: "+dao.CountBill());
        Bill_RecyclerView_Adapter adapter = new Bill_RecyclerView_Adapter(bills,Bill.this,dao);
        bill_RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new      LinearLayoutManager(Bill.this,RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));
        bill_RecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    }
```

bill_total is the textView i use to count the bill with the function in DAO class named CountBill()

```
    public int CountBill(){
        SQLiteDatabase database = sqLite.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = database.rawQuery("select * from bill ",new String[]{});
        int sum = c.getCount();
        c.close();
        return sum;
    }
```

And here is the RecyclerView Adapter

```
    package anhtuan.example.sample.Bill;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import anhtuan.example.sample.DAO.DAO;
    import anhtuan.example.sample.Model.BillModel;
    import anhtuan.example.sample.R;

    public class Bill_RecyclerView_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Bill_RecyclerView_Viewholder> {

    ArrayList<BillModel> bills;
    Context context;
    DAO dao;

    public Bill_RecyclerView_Adapter(ArrayList<BillModel> bills, Context context, DAO dao) {
        this.bills = bills;
        this.context = context;
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Bill_RecyclerView_Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)     {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.bill_viewholder,parent,false);
        return new Bill_RecyclerView_Viewholder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Bill_RecyclerView_Viewholder holder, int position) {
        BillModel billModel;
        billModel = bills.get(position);
        holder.picture.setImageBitmap(billModel.BillBookPicture);
        holder.name.setText(billModel.BillBookName);
        holder.category.setText("Tag: "+billModel.BillBookCategory);
        holder.date.setText("Date: "+billModel.BillDate);
        holder.money.setText("Money: "+billModel.BillMoney);
        holder.sale.setText("Sale: "+billModel.BillSale);
        holder.totalSale.setText("Total: "+billModel.BillTotalSale);
        holder.del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dao.BillDel(billModel.id);
                bills = dao.getDSBill();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bills.size();
    }
    }
```

Comment: you need to remove bill or other.?

Comment: Not It's not exactly the event of deleting bills, actually I've already passed that part and my RecyclerView can automatically reset after deleting. The problem I have is that I don't know how to reset the number of existing invoices in the database when the program executes the command to delete data on the adapter and then set the text back to the bill_total textview.

Comment: okay you need to remove or update data from database and getCount() from database and set into RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/20015640/urvish-shiroya recommend me about the interface callback, it kinda hard to understand clearly but i think i got a hand of it.
All i need to do here is to create an interface file named ViewUpdater then create a class interface in it:

```
    public interface ViewUpdater {
    void CallBack(TextView id);
    }
```

Then create a void class to setText in Bill activity:

```
    public void SetText(ViewUpdater view){
        view.CallBack(bill_total);

    }
```

Finally call it in the onBindViewHolder at the deleted button for it to automatic the Bill count after i delete a bill:

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Bill_RecyclerView_Viewholder holder, int position) {
        BillModel billModel;
        billModel = bills.get(position);
        holder.picture.setImageBitmap(billModel.BillBookPicture);
        holder.name.setText(billModel.BillBookName);
        holder.category.setText("Tag: "+billModel.BillBookCategory);
        holder.date.setText("Date: "+billModel.BillDate);
        holder.money.setText("Money: "+billModel.BillMoney);
        holder.sale.setText("Sale: "+billModel.BillSale);
        holder.totalSale.setText("Total: "+billModel.BillTotalSale);
        holder.del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dao.BillDel(billModel.id);
                bills = dao.getDSBill();
                ((Bill)context).SetText(new ViewUpdater() {
                    @Override
                    public void CallBack(TextView id) {
                        id.setText("Bills: "+dao.CountBill()+"");
                    }
                });
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
```

Hope this help with someone has the same problem